# iPhone Cocoa Touch: Adding additional view or sub view to views

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios4

From What I understand based on what I read, most of the time we will be dealing with view when creating apps for the iPhone. Adding sub view to table view, adding table view to a UIView....etc

So my question is how do I go about mix and match all the views? Let say I start off by using a template in Xcode (Tab Bar Application) which basically give me 2 "section", a tab bar controller with 2 UIView to began with. I modified the code for the UIView so that I end up with 2 table view. Now I wanted to an add additional view to the table view whenever I tap on a cell on the table view. I create a new view controller call firstDetailView and hook them up but nothing happen. Surprisingly the app doesn't crash.

I might do it wrongly or have missed something. I am a newbies to programming. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deal with different views which are handled by a view controller you should read the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10)

- Navigation through views will be done with a Navigation Controller ([Guide here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1))
- Tab bar's are explained as well ([Guide here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1))

Try to read the Apple documentation in the first hand, they are pretty good and all basic stuff is explained there.

Comment: Thanks Brutella. I will read through the documentation tonight.

Comment: After spending hours searching the stack. I think I found my answer.

"Replace your UITableViewController with a UIViewController. Then add a UITableView to your view controller. Set the delegate and datasource of your table view to your view controller. Now you can add a subview in a non-scrolling view-controller, still having your tableview."

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541428/add-details-view-to-uitableview